# want to get BottomTabNavigator separate components

Tags: react-native

i create bottom tab navigator in menu page and in there has two export components. when I try to apply rudex to it want only one components.therefore I want to get separately bottom tab navigator.

Comment: Please try better english. It's hard to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `export default` for component that is not connected to redux.
use `export const COMPONENT_NAME`. for another component that you eant to connect to redux, use this

```
export default connect(mapStatteToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ANOTHER_COMPONENT_NAME)
```

so for importing component use `import {COMPONENT_NAME} from 'pathToComponent'`